# Continuing on Exception

Tags: c#

We have a windows service which does the following
a. Get the files in a particular directory
b. Decrypt the file
c. Split the data in the file
d. Insert the data in the database

As of now, it is implemented in such a way that on first exception, it will terminate the process and the file causing the error is moved out to another folder. Successfully processed files remain in the same location. Due to this, at any point of time only the top most files which are not generating exceptions are getting processed. Rest of them are left out. We are forced to frequently restart the service to get all the files processed. Now we have to change the design in such a way that, even in the chance of exception with a particular file, we should continue with the remaining files.  We have the following Ideas

a. Move the processed files also to another location when they are successfully processed
b. Make a recursive method call for the same method which processes the files in the finally block.

Please suggest us the best way out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

catch the exception, do some logging and just continue with the remaining files ?
I do not see the problem

```
foreach( File f in filesToProcess )
{
    try
    {
        ProcessFile (f);
        MoveFile (f);
    }
    catch( IOException ex )
    {
        Log ("File could not be processed");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but I think it is very important to emphasize that catching *explicit* exception types like this answer demonstrates it is the correct thing to do. Do not catch and suppress System.Exception!

Comment: As far as possible try to avoid catch blocks (you can use try finally blocks), If its really necessary catch very specific exceptions that you might need instead of catching general exceptions.

Comment: If you do not use a catch block, then the exception won't be handled.  It will bubble up on the stack until a catch block is found, and if none is found, and the exception remains unhandled, the application will terminate.
try / finally has other semantics then try / catch.